# Does Apache benchmark simulate more than 100 users login a website?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

If not , is there any other tools can fit this needs?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `ab --help`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jmeter - It's an opensource load testing tool to simulate load of users with required scenarios.